# Regex until character but if not preceded by another character

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I wanted to create a regex to match a string that sharts with `Localize("` and should end when a `"` pops up, but not when `"` is escaped (preceded by `\`).

My current regex which doesnt take into acount that "unless preceded by" looks like:

```
\bLocalize\(\"(.+?)(?=\")
```

Any ideas ?

## EDIT

With the following string:

```
Localize("/Windows/Actions/DeleteActionWarning=The action you are trying to \"delete\" is referenced in this document.") + " Want to Proceed ?";
```

I want it to stop after `document.` comes, because it is the first `"` to show up without a trailing `\` (which shows up around `delete`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\bLocalize\("([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)
```

See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Wk8dpn/2).

**Details**:

- `\bLocalize` - a whole word `Localize`
- `\("` - a `("` substring
- `([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^"\\]*` - 0 or more chars other than `"` and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`  - 0 or more repetitions of an escaped char followed with 0 or more chars other than `"` and `\`

In Python, declare the pattern with

```
reg = r'\bLocalize\("([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)'
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/eYZg9b):

```
import re
reg = r'\bLocalize\("([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)'
s = "Localize(\"/Windows/Actions/DeleteActionWarning=The action you are trying to \\\"delete\\\" is referenced in this document.\") + \" Want to Proceed ?\";"
m = re.search(reg, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# => /Windows/Actions/DeleteActionWarning=The action you are trying to \"delete\" is referenced in this document.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the not regex operator ^

> \bLocalize(\".*?[^\]\"

Comment: Well that doesn't make it stop correctly, at least in Debuggex -> For instance, this string : 

Localize("/Windows/Actions/DeleteActionWarning=The action you are trying to \"delete\" is referenced in this document.") + " Want to Proceed ?";

I want it to stop after "document." comes, because it is the first " to show up without a trailing \ (which shows up around "delete")

Comment: Edited the question with a proper example if it is of any help, thank you tho !